# DJI API Reference doesn't mention m100?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm needing telemetry data including motor output for my onboard application, but the API reference here doesn't mention M100 anywhere-- even in velocity or angular rate -- but it's one of the onboard supported devices, so how come?

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/group__telem.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M100 doesn't support "subscribe" function.ALL topics belong to the "subscribe" function.So it doesn't mention M100. For M100,you can call ["Broadcast" funtion](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/classDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1DataBroadcast.html).